# Object and variable allocation in pandas and numpy python

Tags: python

I am new to python.
I don't understand the principle that pandas follows when allocating pd.DataFrame to new variables.
In the following example I would expect a to retain its value and not changed after a new element is added to b.
Below there is a similar example with np.array, which exhibits the expected behavior.
Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks!

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a=pd.DataFrame([[18, 'F'],[50, 'M']],columns = ('Age','Sex'))
>>> print(a)

   Age Sex
0   18   F
1   50   M

>>> b=a
>>> print(b)

   Age Sex
0   18   F
1   50   M

>>> b.loc[b.index.max() + 1] = [30,'M']
>>> print(b)

   Age Sex
0   18   F
1   50   M
2   30   M

>>> print(a)

   Age Sex
0   18   F
1   50   M
2   30   M

>>> c=np.array([[18,'F'],[50,'M']])
>>> print(c)

[['18' 'F']
 ['50' 'M']]

>>> d=c
>>> print(d)

[['18' 'F']
 ['50' 'M']]

>>> d = np.append(d,[[30,'M']], axis=0)
>>> print(d)

[['18' 'F']
 ['50' 'M']
 ['30' 'M']]

>>> print(c)

[['18' 'F']
 ['50' 'M']]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `b=a`, `a` and `b` are both references to exactly the same object.  Any change made via one name is equally visible via the other name.

The situation with `d=c` is slightly different, because you afterwards reassign `d` to the result of `np.append()`, which is documented as always returning a new object (rather than modifying the object in place).  From that point onward, `c` and `d` are independent objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
b = a.copy()
```

then b will not change while modifying a, because they refer to two different objects.

Back to the question, a and b refer to the same object, `b.loc[b.index.max() + 1] = [30,'M']` just modifies the object, thus both `print(a)` and `print(b)` change.

While c and d refer to the same object, `d = np.append(d,[[30,'M']], axis=0)` update the d, which means now d refer to a new object. But c still refers to the old object.